# CORS AJAX domain rest request

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I have a url that is returns the xml data and it is uses the url with username and password.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myserver.com:port/BC/rest/productslist/',
    data: {
        'username': 'username', 
        'password': 'password'
    },
    dataType: "jsonp", // for cross domain
    contentType: "application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + window.btoa("username" + ":"+ "password"));
    },    
    success: function(sucessResponse) { 
        alert('PUT completed' + sucessResponse); 
    } ,
    error: function(failResponse){
        alert("Error: Something went wrong" + JSON.stringify(failResponse));
    }   
});
```

Problem: When I am testing the code it is showing the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' error.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like that request is returning HTML when you're expecting JSON.

Comment: Can't force an API to return jsonp if it doesn't serve jsonp.  Inspect the actual request in dev tools network tab to see exactly what response body contains

Comment: The request will return the data in xml. first i used the "data-type:xml" it returned the error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin '' is therefore not allowed access.     But when i used the "data-type:jsonp" it returned the data in network response tab with unexpected token <'error. thats why i used it.